# Add padding while generating thumbnail

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

I wanted to know, if there is any function to handle following case:
I have registered image size of 200x200, Now if user uploads 100x100 or 800x120 the thumbnail of 200x200 will not be generated. I want to generate 200x200 by adding padding to thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in functions to *size-up* an image.  You might be able to accomplish what you are looking for by using [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) and an Image processor like [GD or Imagegick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) if your host supports it. Normally at least one of them is supported.

So `wp_get_attachment_metadata` returns an `array` on success or bool `false` on failure.  So given (pseudocode):

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );

if( $thumbnail['width'] < 100 || $thumbnail['height'] < 100 ){

  do_image_padding( $thumbnail, $width = 200, $height = 200 );

}
```

Now of course `do_image_padding` doesn't exist in WP, but it's possible with GD library to create this function that would take in as parameters, the `thumbnail`, the `width` and the `height` and render the new image with padding.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592698/4643867) extensive explanation using GD by bumberbox over at stackoverflow should put you on the right track to built that `do_image_padding` function.